# How does this javascript timer using parseInt work?

Tags: timer, setinterval, parseint

I can't figure out how this commonly-shared javascript timer works. So I understand it uses parseInt and the value of timer to derive the minutes and seconds and uses setInterval to run each second, updating the values each time. My question is what is causing the value of the timer variable to change producing minutes and seconds values that count down. For example, first run minutes are 1, seconds are 0. Next run minutes are 0, seconds are 59. Next run seconds are 58, then 57 etc. How does the value change? I see no decrementing. What am I missing here?

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

Comment: `parseInt(...)` reads a string (hopefully with a numeric value) and turns it into a number for doing math calculation on it.  If the string does not have a number, it cannot parse it and throws an error

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/timer-function-question/407582
It's decrementing in the if statement `if(--timer<0)`.